# php script needs to open a new window and load jquery files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

*** EDITED: ***

I have a php script that calls a js function, the js opens a new windows and load jquery on it.

The problem is that the jquery file is not loading on the new window, please see the code below:

```
<?php
    echo "<a href='javascript:void(0);' target='MMMM' onclick='linkTest()'>LINK</a>";
?>

<script>

function linkTest()
{
var w = window.open();

var s = w.document.createElement(script);
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);

var s = w.document.createElement(script);
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js";
w.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
}
</script>
```

thank you very much

Comment: Why would the files be loaded before the window opens? I can't really see any reason why the javascript files would be missing, but maybe I'm not getting this at all !

Comment: Hi Adeneo, thanks for your quick response, the code above is not working for me I debug the app using google chrome and the js files are missing from the new window. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you got a jsfiddle or a test page that we can look at?

Comment: `w.document.createElement(script)` should be `w.document.createElement("script")`

Comment: eithedog u are right and got my problem fixed, my shame... this is what happens when you code using notepad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION by eithedog:

```
<?php
    echo "<a href='javascript:void(0);' target='MMMM' onclick='linkTest()'>LINK</a>";
?>

<script>

function linkTest()
{
var w = window.open();

var s = w.document.createElement("script");
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);

var s = w.document.createElement("script");
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js";
w.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use write method to write in new window like

```
 var var w = window.open("", timeStamp);

  var str = "All The Things you want to put in new window.";
  // i.e str = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html><head><link href='styleprint.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><script type='text/javascipt' src=''></script></head><body>"+Content+"</body></html>";
  w.document.write(str);
```

Comment: give link to javascript file as in parent window.

Comment: really? `document.write()`? We stopped using that in 1994.